# Ubuntu 18 update/reboot lost keyboard & mouse (all) inputs

Tags: 18.04

Using Ubuntu 18 latest apt update. After a Canonical update & reboot I don't have any (any!) mouse or keyboard input to the system. I've spent several hours trying to trouble shoot the issue without any success. I'm not sure where in the gobbeldygook of folders & files I should look for a fix. Most help is very welcome, especially if the helper knows what they are talking about. As you see I'm a little stressed

Comment: Sorry, we all understand your frustration, but please provide more details. Is it a laptop? did you try to plug any usb device? did you try to see if the keyboard works in the grub or even in the bios? did you access the system from a live in order to say that you are looking for folders and file? From your question this is not clear. I'm sorry though, I don't have the answer to your question.

Comment: Hi,  Yes it's a Dell Inspiron 5000 series.   The mouse & keyboard work until the OS loads, then no input device works.  Yes about live boot (DVD), can access all files on the HD (mouse * kb working.)  Is there a way to update the non-booted OS on the HD. Doesn't seem likely. Sorry for the delay in response, but many projects take up time.. By the way thank you for your concern, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a way to load the the non booted OS and I believe it would work for performing an `apt update`. I once did it in order repair the boot process with and `update-grub`; it involves mounting all the partitions that refer to your system and then `chroot` inside them, but it don't think you would need to go this far to perform an update. 
I wrote you and answer proposing a way to update the system.

Comment: Anyway, if I wanted to search for some error at boot time I would normally search them in the journal with `journalctl` or `dmesg`. I think you can find the same informations in some log file inside `/var/log/`. Probably `/var/log/syslog` contains some useful info, but carefull that it contains many days of logging, so start your research from the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to update your system in order to see if it solves the problem.

Since you can't do anything from your system, I suggest you to create a script with a couple of lines, that do the update for you.
Then you should set up your system in order to run such script at startup.

```
#!/bin/bash

apt update

apt upgrade -y
```

In order to run the script at boot time you have various options, and of course you need to find one that could be activate from another OS.
One option is to use `crontab`,  but they highly recommend to avoid editing cronfiles by hand, but since you cannot have access to the system file you would need to do so.
Another option is insert the script in `/etc/rc.local` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu).
In any case I recommend you to investigate this more.

---

Side note:
`apt` is not actually script friendly, but for what you need it, it shouldn't be a big deal. I'm sure there are other ways to perform an update with a script if you really need so.